# i created a table with compoite primary key(assign to two columns) and craed another table refering foreign key for only one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The screenshots from `sql-server` :

> [image]

[image: 2]

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question has no (useful) text and images that I cannot read.  Code and errors should be *text* in the questions, not unreadable images.

Answer (score 0):

your students table has a composite primary key, so the foreign key must include all of them

Answer (score 0):

The Foreign Key is on the wrong table.  Instead of a FK on Department refering to Student, put the Foreign Key on Student, referring to Department, which should have a Primary Key of DepartmentId (and don't put `.` in your column names, and don't abbreviate).